# Language change in textbox in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight

I am new in silverlight ,I have more than two textbox in a UI, what i want to do is there will be a textbox with a label secondary name,on that text box when user type anything it should come in arabic language!

I mean when users focused on a textbox control the default language need to change to arabic.

I have seen same questions in this stackoverklow,but the answer i saw was saying how to do resource switching of languages of labels,buttons etc. but my question is how can i change the language when i type in a textbox control,Hope u get my point.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add the TextChanged event handler and change the CurrentUICulture property. After that all labels should be changed if you have configured binding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through an API call if you're trying to put the translated text into the label. [This link](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-with-Bing-Translator-Services.aspx) shows example code on how to use the Bing Translation API in Silverlight.